# Why is this tmux option not persisting?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, tmux

I would like to generate a `bashrc` configuration file each time I start a particular tmux session, and I want to use my user's default tmux configuration file `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/tmux/tmux.conf` as well. This same configuration should be reused with each window/pane created in any given session.

To prevent race conditions when starting multiple sessions simultaneously, I would like to avoid moving/relinking/etc. the default `bashrc`/`tmux.conf` configuration file each time, as that seems really hairy.

Instead, I am trying to invoke tmux with a dynamic configuration file that performs the following:

1. Create a temporary file containing my generated `bashrc` configuration (say, `/tmp/bashrc.12345`)
2. Set the `default-command` option in tmux similar to `bash --rcfile /tmp/bashrc.12345 [-i|-l|...] [ARGV...]` (depending on how tmux was invoked)
3. `source-file` my user's default `tmux.conf`

This looks similar to the following shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tmuxrc="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/tmux/tmux.conf"

bashrc=$( mktemp )
generate-bashrc > "${bashrc}"

# This is the tmux configuration file's final content
config="set-option -g default-command 'bash --rcfile \"${bashrc}\"' ; source-file '${tmuxrc}' ;"
# Reordering the statements makes no apparent difference
#config="source-file '${tmuxrc}' ; set-option -g default-command 'bash --rcfile \"${bashrc}\"' ;"

exec tmux -f <( echo "${config}" ) "${@}"
```

When running this script, I can see my default tmux configuration file is being loaded, applying my layout/theme and so on, but the `default-command` option is definitely not working like I would expect.

Instead, my default shell is started, and when I print the current options in tmux with `tmux show -sgwp`, it doesn't list `default-command` as being defined at all!

> **EDIT** ≈ Even if I run `tmux set-option -g default-command FOO` (with `FOO` being anything at all) from inside the running tmux session, it still remains undefined according to `tmux show -sgwp`

Why is this option not persisting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this option not persisting?

Many issues with tmux become more understandable when you realize and remember the tmux server and each tmux client are separate processes. In some circumstances a client starts a server. `.tmux.conf` is for the server, not for clients. Similarly `-f` (that specifies an alternative configuration file) is for the server.

Your `exec tmux -f <( echo "${config}" ) "${@}"` execs to a tmux client. The client may or may not start a tmux server. It will start a server if there is no server yet. If it starts a server then `-f` will work.

In your case `-f` will matter for the first `tmux` command, the one that doesn't find a server and has to start one. You are "starting multiple sessions simultaneously", so your subsequent `tmux` commands will find the server and their `-f` will be irrelevant. The server may exit later and if you run your script after this then it's all over again: one `tmux` command will start a *new* server, so its `-f` will matter; but as long as the server remains, `-f` in subsequent invocations of your `tmux -f …` won't matter.

See the [manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#f) [emphasis mine]:

> `-f file`
> Specify an alternative configuration file. […] **tmux loads configuration files once when the server process has started. The `source-file` command may be used to load a file later.**

---

The command `tmux set-option -g default-command FOO` defines a global session option. To see global session options you need `tmux show -g` (i.e. without `-s`, `-w`, `-p`). The whole mechanics of options in tmux is [kinda complicated](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#OPTIONS).